# Creating a Erlang binary through NIF with data pointing to a char *

Tags: c, erlang, erlang-nif

I'm doing a C-Erlang integration using NIF and I'm having some trouble to initialize a `Binary` and add a `char*` pointing to its data.

I'm doing this way:

```
ErlNifBinary *output_binary;
enif_alloc_binary(500, output_binary);

strcpy(output_binary->data, "Here is a string");
return enif_make_binary(env, output_binary);
```

Any ideas about what I'm not doing right? I'm getting a segmentation fault.

**UPDATE**: I get rid of the segmentation fault. But now I can't return a Erlang binary containing a `String`.

Using `enif_make_string` with the `binary.data` I get a `String` on Erlang. But when I try to use `enif_make_binary` with the binary, I get things like this `<<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,112,40,129,20>>` what do I need to do to convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the problem.

I was supposed to return the address of a binary not a binary so just a `return enif_make_binary(env, &output_binary);` make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate memory for the `output_binary` object  but `output_binary->data` points to an invalid object. You can allocate memory for `output_binary->data` this way:

```
output_binary->data = malloc(sizeof "Here is a string");  // or enif_alloc
strcpy(output_binary->data, "Here is a string");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work here. 

I'm still getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: You also have to set `output_binary->size` to `sizeof "Here is a string"`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but I couldn't get a Erlang binary with a String. (I've updated the question)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's looking for this, it's actually easy in C or C++.

You need to allocate the `ErlNifBinary` object (not the string). Once you have created the `ERL_NIF_TERM` through a call to `enif_make_binary` the `ErlNifBinary` becomes read-only and ownership is transferred to the `ERL_NIF_TERM`. You can effectively forget about the `ErlNifBinary` object.

```
ErlNifBinary bin;
std::string str = "hi there";

enif_alloc_binary(str.size(), &bin);

strcpy((char*)bin.data, str.c_str());
bin.size = str.size();

ERL_NIF_TERM term = enif_make_binary(env,&bin);
```

If you are working in pure C a static string works just as well.

```
ErlNifBinary bin;
const char * str = "hi there";

enif_alloc_binary(strlen(str), &bin);

strcpy((char*)bin.data, str);
bin.size = strlen(str);

ERL_NIF_TERM term = enif_make_binary(env,&bin);
```